# Animate changing a slider's maximum value

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider

I am trying to animate a slider when setting the new maximum value. I set the maximum value, as such:

*You may be confused to why there is a `.slider` property - it's my own custom class.*

```
fingerSizeSlider.slider.maximumValue = Float(newValue) + 0.99
```

I have tried using `UIView.animate` which did not work, and I cannot do the following:

```
fingerSizeSlider.slider.setValue(fingerSizeSlider.slider.value, animated: true)
```

---

The slider thumb automatically moves (which is good) but it does not animate, and the line of code directly above has no effect (because obviously, I am setting to the same value).

How can I animate this `maximumValue` property of the slider?

[Here is a video to illustrate the issue (a gif is too choppy).](https://streamable.com/gfe4q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slider draws itself using private subviews. You need to animate the layout of those subviews.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
   fingerSizeSlider.slider.maximumValue = Float(newValue) + 0.99
   fingerSizeSlider.slider.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```

Comment: The perfect quick answer I needed, I will accept it when I can! :)